# Spawning 100 threads and incrementing a shared counter, can this be optimzed/improved to complete in 1 second?

Tags: rust

I wanted to learn how to write this Go code in Rust, the go code is here for reference: https://go.dev/play/p/j9osOG5xs1R

It basically launches 100 threads, and in each thread in loops 1000 times, sleeping for 1 millisecond on each iteration and also increments some shared state.

Since it sleeps for 1 millisecond, it should complete in 1 second.

In my Go version, I actually create 100 threads and it completes in about 1 second as expected.

My rust code currently only has 10 threads, and takes 10 seconds to complete.

**I must be doing something wrong, any tips on improving the performance?**

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let counter = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
    let mut handles = vec![];

    use std::time::Instant;
    let now = Instant::now();

    for _ in 0..10 {
        let counter = Arc::clone(&counter);
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {

            let mut num = counter.lock().unwrap();

            for _ in 0..1000 {
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1));
                *num += 1;
            }
        });
        handles.push(handle);
    }

    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }

    println!("Result: {}", *counter.lock().unwrap());

    let elapsed = now.elapsed();
    println!("Elapsed: {:.2?}", elapsed);
}
```

I even built the program in release mode also:

```
cargo build --release
./target/release/spawner
```

It for some reason takes over 10 seconds for only 10 threads...

Comment: From a glance the obvious difference is in your `go` code you have used atomic operations to update the data which is expected to be lock-free but in Rust you have locked the object to update the data. To make a better comparison please try using [atomics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/) in Rust too.

Comment: I think you confuse thread and coroutine, you never create any thread in your go code, at least not yourself. Your two code snipped are fundamentally different. You should look for async Rust.

Comment: @Stargateur isn't the thread created in my rust code a type of green thread? or its a real thread?

Comment: @Blankman no std::thread are real thread from OS that the first sentence of doc https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/index.html

Comment: I want to repeat @ÖmerErden's note though: the Go code uses atomics, the Rust code uses mutexes, so you're comparing rather different situation (aside from the dissimilar threading). You could also skip a few allocations by using [the recent *scoped threads* feature](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=429d529b67505b1bf07e8e9688c74c6c).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each thread locks `counter` for the entire 1 second it runs, blocking all of the threads from making any progress. This causes them to run sequentially rather than in parallel.

If you shrink the scope of the lock then they'll grab and release the mutex each millisecond, unblocking each other and allowing the program to finish in the expected 1 second.

```rust
let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
    for _ in 0..1000 {
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1));
        let mut num = counter.lock().unwrap();
        *num += 1;
    }
});
```

Output:

```
Result: 10000
Elapsed: 1.09s
```

Comment: would using async make this faster?  Is this a real thread or a green thread or the likes thereof...

Comment: @Blankman in this case this is a CPU-bound operation, async is mostly suited for IO-bound operations, so it won't make it faster.

Comment: @RicardoMurillo sleeping is not CPU bound so `async` may remove some overhead, especially if the number of tasks becomes very large. Benchmarking is the only way to be sure.

Comment: @Blankman something else that could remove overhead is to use [atomic operations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/sync/atomic/index.html) instead of a `Mutex`.

Comment: I tried switching it to use `tokio` and it ended up taking ~2.3 seconds instead of 1.09. I don't know why. Sync mutex vs. async mutex vs. AtomicU32 made no difference. Guess: Is 1ms too short of a time interval for an async sleep? Perhaps there's a lot of timer noise at such a small interval.

Comment: The main problem is that there is not enough contention to make a difference. I increased the number of threads to `10_000` and atomic was significantly faster than sync mutex (4.5s vs 5s). Tokio is worse (tokio + atomic takes 8s).

Comment: @JohnKugelman If the concern is comparing Mutex with Atomic then what is the point of 1ms sleep?

Comment: @Jmb indeed, i mean, the CPU-bound operation here is the add operation, mentioned just as a general rule of thumb. Also keep in mind `async` adds a bit of overhead given the code is transformed.

Comment: @ÖmerErden Blankman asked if async would be faster. I figured it might be so I tried it out. For some reason `tokio` is actually slower and I don't know why. I did a few minutes of investigation. It's not because of the mutex; I eliminated that possibility. But I didn't keep investigating.

Comment: @JohnKugelman probably b/c tokio has its own custom scheduler...which is not as effecient.  Can you paste your tokio code please?

Comment: [Tokio version on Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=78f5613e93aefa7d11792730da07d4dc)

Comment: @JohnKugelman  From this [code in playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8f2e1499375aa4e0d6dbb95a4a7b1eda), it looks like `tokio::time::sleep` requires additional `~1ms` to complete the sleep task, or its accuracy tolerance is `~1ms` for each sleep task. In your example numbers show like the total time is doubled but not really, it is because you have used `1ms`. I used different sleep times in example to show that